# Action after nuget uninstall

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

My NuGet package requires copying some static files after installation from the central `.nuget` location to the project location. I solved that by adding a custom `.target` file to the package and copying is triggered after build.

```xml
<Target AfterTargets="Build">
 <Copy SourceFiles="@(SourceModuleFiles)"
   DestinationFolder="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\MyDestination
   SkipUnchangedFiles="true"/>
</Target>
```

Not perfect, but acceptable. Problem is that I would like to remove these files after the package uninstalls because I need to do it manually now. It used to be a funcionality to run `tools/uninstall.ps1` which could do the job, but it is no longer supported by nuget.
Is there another way to do it? Unable to find anything reasonable.

Comment: It sounds like you're solving the wrong problem - you might be better off working out how to make your package work when those files stay alongside it